# SSD Great on paper but practically randomly slows

Tags: ssd, performance

I have Adata SU650 Sata 2.5” SSD. The SSD is in use for last about 3 years. Causal laptop usage. The Adata’s SSD Toolbox app on Windows 10 reports Good health, temps around 33 Deg C and about 100% health remaining. The SMART is also fine. The SSD is certainly good on paper.

However many a times when I run CrystalDiskMark speed test it reports sequential read speed of say 400 MB/S but sequential write speeds just 10 - 20MB/S other times simply great at 455 MB/S.
Many a times while copying a single large file say 5GB sized, it starts with say 200MB/S speed and then it falls to just 10 MB/S for a few seconds then again goes up/down/up/down like that randomly.

I tried TRIM operation but it did not help.

I have several other SSDs e.g. Samsung 970 EVO. It never shows such a behavior. Every speed test it’s consistently good. And speed never falls while copying a single large file.
Do I have any problem with my SSD which is undetected by these health monitoring apps? There’s over 30% space unoccupied.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1**

Just to mention, this behavior has started very recently, just since about 2  - 3weeks ago or so. For entire 3 years there was no such problem. So if this is because of absence of DRAM cache ideally it should have been consistent since day 1. I am always concerned with SSD speeds so every week I have been running CrystalDIskMark test regularly for last 3 years.

Answer (score 3):

Adata SU650 doesn't have DRAM cache. This is a cost-saving measure used in cheaper SSDs. It will cause the performance drops in certain workloads and explains what you're observing.

Comment: long story short, you get what you pay for.